# Mapbox view is blank in my fragment, and no errors

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, mapbox

I've added Mapbox into a fragment. The editor doesn't show any errors while compiling, but the view of which the map is supposed to be is just gray. I know the view of the map is there because the fragment is gray like Mapbox is supposed to be, while the other blank fragments are white. I've tested all the [common fixes](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/blank-tiles/) from Mapbox. Why isn't the map being rendered?

I've tried looking for errors in Logcat and while debugging on external Android device and I can't see any signs of Mapbox failing. It shows the map neither in emulator nor a physical device.

The kotlin code for the fragment

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.Mapbox
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.Style
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_home.*


// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private const val ARG_PARAM1 = "param1"
private const val ARG_PARAM2 = "param2"

/**
 * A simple [Fragment] subclass.
 *
 */
class Home : Fragment() {

    private var mapView: MapView? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        // Mapbox Access token
        Mapbox.getInstance(requireContext(), R.string.mapbox_access_token.toString())


        mapView = map_view
        mapView?.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        mapView?.getMapAsync { mapboxMap ->

            mapboxMap.setStyle(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS) {

                // Map is set up and the style has loaded. Now you can add data or make other map adjustments



            }

        }
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)


    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        mapView?.onStart()
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        mapView?.onPause()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        mapView?.onResume()
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        mapView?.onStop()
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        mapView?.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    }

    override fun onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory()
        mapView?.onLowMemory()
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        mapView?.onDestroy()
    }


}
```

The layout file for the fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
             tools:context=".Home">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/map_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            mapbox:mapbox_cameraTargetLat="-36.84"
            mapbox:mapbox_cameraTargetLng="174.76"
            mapbox:mapbox_cameraZoom="10"
            mapbox:mapbox_cameraBearing="34.33"
            mapbox:mapbox_cameraTilt="50.25"
            mapbox:mapbox_cameraZoomMax="12.41"
            mapbox:mapbox_cameraZoomMin="6"
            mapbox:mapbox_uiRotateGestures="false"
    />
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Home Fragment! Map coming soon"/>


</FrameLayout>
```

Everything looks right, except for the map itself...

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the latest version should have some error.
I solved this problem by replacing this dependency on the gradle (module app)

```
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:8.6.0'
```

with

```
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:5.5.1'
```